# Does Google Cloud have an Eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-plugin-eclipse

I use Eclipse and have been happy using Google Plugin for Eclipse (https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/download) for quite some time.  Does Google Cloud have an Eclipse plugin or is the Google Plugin for Eclipse compatible with both App Engine AND Google Cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jordan Fish from Google Cloud Platform Support gave me this answer:

> At this time there is only the AppEngine eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 1):

GPE will soon be decommissioned. Development is continuing rapidly on its successors including [Cloud Tools for Eclipse](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/). (The Android and GWT components of GPE are being handled separately.)

Today Cloud Tools for Eclipse primarily supports App Engine standard environment. However a [peek in the Github repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse) might reveal some big clues about what's coming next.

Answer (score 0):

If Google Cloud Platform's Eclipse support ever handles more than App Engine, it will be via the Google Plugin for Eclipse.